# Error: Can't open included file 'math.h'

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

This is the Fortran program I tried to run it in Code::Blocks:

```
include 'math.h'
program helloworld
real::x,y
complex::done
x=2;
y=3;
done=complx(x,y)
print *,done
end program
```

I have Windows 8.1 and Code::Blocks. What could be the problem?

Comment: BTW, the fact that you have svn is absolutely irrelevant (do you even know what it is?). The compiler and your operating system you have is the almost only important thing. And you didn't even tell us your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You do not include `math.h` in Fortran. There is no reason to do such a thing.

It is done in the C programming language, but not in Fortran. And also not in many other programming languages.

Just delete the include line, it is useless.

Alse, the intrinsic function to create a complex number is `cmplx()`, not `complx()`.

Also, you do not need to use any semicolons (`;`), but it is not an error.